# Voltage difference between two points in an AC circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current, potential

[image][image: This was a question asked in a coaching's national test]
How do I approach this problem using phasor methods and how can I calculate voltage difference between two points in an AC circuit(wouldn't the phase difference between the potential values of the two points make any difference to the potential difference between the points?)?(the correct answer to the question in the image is 20 volts.)edit question::::Have I placed the points A and B correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This made me think. It is an instructive question, possibly meriting the epithet 'classic'. Here are a few hints.

Prepare to sketch phasor diagrams of voltage addition for both top and bottom branches on the same phasor diagram with a common line (I chose horizontal, starting at the origin and pointing right) for the applied voltage, *U*.

Use the head-to-tail construction for adding the voltage phasors in the top branch. Put the tail of the $V_{R1}$ phasor at the origin. You should get a right angled triangle.

Repeat for the bottom branch with the tail of the $V_C$ phasor at the origin.

You should find that the points representing the potentials of A and B do not co-incide. The distance separating them is a phasor whose length you have been told. The phase difference that you mention has been automatically dealt with.

Exploiting symmetries in the diagram you can find the value of $U$. I reached it via a simple quadratic equation, but you don't need this if you are just checking which one of the given answers fits. Good luck!

Comment: Sir how did you find the points A and B in phasor diagram?(I am sorry I am a rookie at phasors.)

Comment: A and B are the where R1 joins L and where C joins R2, so in the phasor diagram their potentials correspond to the points where the R1 phasor joins the L phasor, and where the C phasor joins the R2 phasor.

Comment: or Sir can you please upload an image of rough phasor diagram (hand drawn would do.)

Comment: No: that's for you to do! This is not the easiest of phasor diagram questions, and I recommend some more practice with simpler ones.

Comment: Sir for the two branches would the applied potential act as the common diagonal of two rectangles

Comment: Yes, but I'd recommend that you use triangles to add the phasors rather than rectangles. The diagram will be simpler.

Comment: Ok Sir thanks for your help

Comment: Sir i am editing my question and posting the phasor i have drawn can you please verify

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134113/discussion-between-sarvesh-maheshwari-and-philip-wood).

Comment: Good try. You've got the phase relationships right. But do what I recommended and, for the top branch, put the tail of the $V_{R1}$ phasor at the origin. You'll find that both triangles are then below the $U$ phasor. A small point: make the reactive phasors different in length from the resistance phasors, so that you don't get misled by your diagram.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your help